# Need to test opennebula xml-rpc apis using postman

Tags: opennebula

I am new to opennebula. Trying xml-rpc apis with postman but it says timeout connect could not be made. On the other hand when tried same url on browser it says “csrftoken”. can someone please share me a tutorial or any resources that help me fire an api with postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are having issues with the XML-RPC APIs in OpenNebula. The "csrftoken" message you received in your browser comes from Sunstone. You need to interact with the 2616 port instead. For more information, I recommend checking out the OpenNebula documentation at https://docs.opennebula.io/6.6/integration_and_development/system_interfaces/api.html. In case you need some more help from the community, feel free to post your query in the community forum here: https://forum.opennebula.io/. Good luck!